# Using a string to call an object

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create a program that defines the variable `finalResult` based on variable `input`. The `input` variable should call on an object inside of object `A`:

```
var input = "";
var A = {
   AA: {
      result: 0
   },
   AB: {
      result: 1
   }
}
var finalResult = A.input.result;
```

So if `input = "AA"`, then the final result should be 0, but if `input = "AB"`, then the final result should be 1.

Comment: `A[input].result`

Comment: Hey, just use var finalResult = A[input][‘result’];

Comment: You should read about [Javascript property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).
Use bracket notation: in your case, `var finalResult = A[input].result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `A[input].result`, which assumes the value of `input`  is present as a property in `A`. If the property isn’t present you’ll get an error trying to access `result` on `undefined`. You can guard against this by OR’ing it with an empty object:

```js
(A[input] || {}).result // undefined if A[input] isn’t present
```